# how to make pdf page to fit to screen size in vfr reader

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

Has any one used vfr reader in your iPhone application. i am using this vfr reader to show pdf pages. what my need is when a user changes his orientation from portrait to landscape i need to make the pdf page to fit to the entire screen. how can i do this.

Answer (score 5):

Its just a matter of finding the correct Zoom Factor and setting the content offset. In the ReaderContentView.m add the following function to the top of the file

```
static inline CGFloat ZoomScaleThatFills(CGSize target, CGSize source)
{
    return (target.width / source.width);
}
```

in the same file, inside the updateMinimumMaximumZoom Function change the line as follows:

```
CGFloat zoomScale = ZoomScaleThatFills(targetRect.size, theContentView.bounds.size);
```

and finally, in the initWithFrameFunction almost at the very end change the lines as follows:

```
[self updateMinimumMaximumZoom]; // Update the minimum and maximum zoom scales

self.zoomScale = self.minimumZoomScale; // Set zoom to fit page width

// Set Offset to 0 to scroll to top of page         
self.contentOffset = CGPointMake((0.0f - CONTENT_INSET), (0.0f - CONTENT_INSET));
```

that does it for me, hope it works for you as well!

Comment: Perfect - I was tryign to get this done from a logn time - Good job thumbsup

Comment: Can someone explain this in  detail what the target should be and what the source should be? Im setting the target aas the views frame and the source as the readers fraem and the width is ok but the height is not working correctly