# How to make pdf to fit to screen size in vfr reader

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, pdf, ios6

i am using this vfr reader to show pdf pages.i need to make the pdf page to fit to the entire screen. how can i do this. I tried everything but couldn’t get it. Can someone please lead me to in right direction.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848046/how-to-make-pdf-page-to-fit-to-screen-size-in-vfr-reader?rq=1

Comment: you can do this way:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848046/how-to-make-pdf-page-to-fit-to-screen-size-in-vfr-reader

Comment: you can do this way :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7848046/how-to-make-pdf-page-to-fit-to-screen-size-in-vfr-reader

Answer (score 1):

I found a way: Set the statusbar to hidden in `viewWillAppear` of `ReaderViewController`, then set `READER_SHOW_SHADOWS` to `FALSE` and `CONTENT_INSET` to `0` in `ReaderContentView`. Also, make sure your PDF's aspect ratio is 4:3.

Answer (score 0):

In `initWithURL:page:password` method of `ReaderContentPage.m`, you need to set `viewRect.size` to full screen size.